# Layout switch doesn't work on high-numbered tags

Tags: awesome-wm

I have defined 9 tags

```
awful.util.tagnames = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" }
```

However, if my `awful.layout.layouts` field contains less than 9 elements, e.g.,

```
awful.layout.layouts = {
    awful.layout.suit.floating,
    awful.layout.suit.tile,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.left,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.bottom,
    awful.layout.suit.tile.top,
}
```

then layout switching with `MOD+SPACE` doesn't work on the higher numbered tags, in the above example, on tags 6-9.  After inserting additional layouts in `awful.layout.layouts` so that there are 9 elements, everything works as expected.

I'm sure that I have some stupid mistake somewhere, and would appreciate any pointers to what I might be doing wrong.

**EDIT:** I put my `rc.lua` [here](https://gist.github.com/andreas-h/ed88aaa28cda85920a098a9d73b496ce).  "It does not work" means that even though I press `MOD+SPACE`, the layout doesn't get changed (the little icon in the top left corner of the screen continuously shows the "floating layout", and also with the mouse on that icon I cannot change the layout).

Comment: Got a link to your config? Also, what happens exactly when "it does not work"? Nothing?

Comment: see updated question, I added the config. do you also need the theme config?

Comment: Hm, I cannot really reproduce your problem. I did this to your config: https://gist.github.com/psychon/050379169ce2ce0d603111ba1e7152ac The last four lines make awesome print the currently selected tag and its layout each second. With this, I can toggle through all five layouts on tag 1 (via mod4+space) and also on tag 9 (mod4+9, then mod4+space). I cannot say anything about the layouticon, since that's not part of the config that I got (hence the above timer + print trick).